# Creating a Driver for PNI RM3100 compatible with Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am currently developing a driver for the RM3100 magnetometer but am running into issues reading and writing to the registers. Currently, I am trying to read the STATUS register to determine if the sensor is collecting data; however, I get a zero every time. Is there an issue with the way that I am trying to access the registers? Or is there some error in my code?

C++ file:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "QRM3100.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include <math.h>

#define CALIBRATION_TIMEOUT 5000 //timeout in milliseconds
#define DEG_PER_RAD (180.0/3.14159265358979)

QRM3100::QRM3100() {
    //Just some random initial values
}

void QRM3100::initialize() {
    Wire.begin();

}

uint8_t QRM3100::readRegister(uint8_t address){
  uint8_t output;

  Wire.beginTransmission(QRM3100_I2C_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(address);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  delayMicroseconds(20);

  Wire.requestFrom(QRM3100_I2C_ADDRESS, 1);
  while(Wire.available())
  {
    output = Wire.read();
  }

  return output;
}

void QRM3100::writeRegister(uint8_t address, uint8_t value){
  Wire.beginTransmission(QRM3100_I2C_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(address);
  Wire.write(value);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

bool QRM3100::dataReady() {
    return ((readRegister(QRM3100_STATUS_REG) & 0x80) >> 7);
}


void QRM3100::start() {
    exitStandby();
}


void QRM3100::exitStandby(){
    writeRegister(QRM3100_CMM, 0b011100001);
}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef QRM3100_h
#define QRM3100_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Wire.h"

#define QRM3100_CMM         0x01 //initiates continuous measurement mode
#define QRM3100_STATUS_REG      0x34 //status of DRDY
#define QRM3100_I2C_ADDRESS     0x21
#define QRM3100_POLL        0x00 //poll

class QRM3100
{
    public:
    QRM3100();
    void initialize();

    uint8_t readRegister(uint8_t address);
    void writeRegister(uint8_t address, uint8_t value);
    bool dataReady();


    void start();
    void exitStandby();

    bool error;
};

#endif
```

Arduino file:

```
#include <C:\Users\daehy\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\src\QRM3100X.h>
#include <C:\Users\daehy\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\src\QRM3100X.cpp>

QRM3100 mag = QRM3100();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mag.initialize();
  mag.start();
}

void loop() {
 Serial.println( mag.dataReady());
}
```

Comment: What about experimenting/comparing with standard I2C hardware/libraries? (e.g. an RTC)

Comment: We actually used the driver for the MAG3110 as a basis for what we're trying to develop here. Here's the link to the GitHub: https://github.com/sparkfun/MAG3110_Breakout_Board/tree/master/Libraries/Arduino/src

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't set the CMM register first. The default value may not be correct for continuous mode. Try setting the CMM register (0x01) to the following:

(CMM_ALL_AXIS_ON | DRDY_WHEN_ALL_AXIS_MEASURED | CM_START)

---

(      0x70      |             0x08            |   0x01  )
that should give you a final binary value of,

|LDM|CMZ|CMY|CMX|DRDM1|DRDM0|ALARM|START|

---

| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1   | 0   |  0  |  1  |

or  0x79 in hex